# frequency of words in a list based on data in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I have a dataframe that looks like the following

```
Utterance                         Frequency
```

```
Directions to Starbucks           1045
Show me directions to Starbucks   754
Give me directions to Starbucks   612
Navigate me to Starbucks          498
Display navigation to Starbucks   376
Direct me to Starbucks            201
Navigate to Starbucks             180
```

Here, there is some data that show utterances made by people, and how frequently these were said.

I.e., "Directions to Starbucks" was uttered 1045 times, "Show me directions to Starbucks" was uttered 754 times, etc.

I'm trying to get a frequency of how many times individual words were uttered.

I tried using `.value_counts()`, but that only gave me the following

```
Utterance       Frequency
```

```
Starbucks       7
Directions      3
Navigate        2
.
.
.
```

Instead, I am trying to get the following output

```
Utterance       Frequency
```

```
Starbucks       3666
Directions      2411
Navigate        678
.
.
.
```

In other words, I'm trying to get the frequency of how many times they were uttered, not in how many rows they appear, which is what happeend with value.counts()

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an O(n) complexity solution, use `collections.Counter`.

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['Directions to Starbucks', 1045],
                   ['Show me directions to Starbucks', 754],
                   ['Give me directions to Starbucks', 612],
                   ['Navigate me to Starbucks', 498],
                   ['Display navigation to Starbucks', 376],
                   ['Direct me to Starbucks', 201],
                   ['Navigate to Starbucks', 180]],
                  columns = ['Utterance', 'Frequency'])

c = Counter()

for row in df.itertuples():
    for i in row[1].split():
        c[i] += row[2]

res = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(c, orient='index')\
        .rename(columns={0: 'Count'})\
        .sort_values('Count', ascending=False)
```

**Result**

```
            Count
to           3666
Starbucks    3666
me           2065
directions   1366
Directions   1045
Show          754
Navigate      678
Give          612
Display       376
navigation    376
Direct        201
```

**Explanation**

- Loop through each row and each word in each row.
- For each word, increment the counter, using the word as key.
- Create dataframe from resulting dictionary.

Comment: follow-up question (posted below as well), is there a way to join certain words, such as "give, show, nagivate, direct, and me"? during this process?

for example, if i want to combine phrasal verbs, so i can get an output like...

phrasal_verbs (direct, give, show, nagivate) = 2065

Comment: I would create a mapping between these words and a group tuple, then perform the same process. For a full solution, I suggest you ask as a separate question.

Comment: posted here, please take a look if you can:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49496102/mapping-between-words-and-a-group-tuple-to-get-frequency-of-words

Answer (score 2):

I think need:

```
df = (df.set_index('Frequency')['Utterance']
        .str.split(expand=True)
        .stack()
        .groupby(level=0)
        .value_counts()
        .reset_index(name='new')
        .assign(Frequency = lambda x: x.Frequency * x['new'])
        .groupby('level_1', as_index=False)['Frequency'].sum()
        .rename(columns={'level_1':'Words'})
        )
print (df)
         Words  Frequency
0       Direct        201
1   Directions       1045
2      Display        376
3         Give        612
4     Navigate        678
5         Show        754
6    Starbucks       3666
7   directions       1366
8           me       2065
9   navigation        376
10          to       3666
```

If each row contain only unique words solution is simplify:

```
df = (df.set_index('Frequency')['Utterance']
        .str.split(expand=True)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(name='Words')
        .groupby('Words', as_index=False)['Frequency'].sum()
        )
print (df)
         Words  Frequency
0       Direct        201
1   Directions       1045
2      Display        376
3         Give        612
4     Navigate        678
5         Show        754
6    Starbucks       3666
7   directions       1366
8           me       2065
9   navigation        376
10          to       3666
```

**Explanation**:

1. Create index from column `Frequency`
2. [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) sentences to words to `DataFrame`
3. Reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)
4. Get counts per group by [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html)
5. Multiple count column with `Frequency` by [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)
6. Aggregate `sum` by words with [`GroupBy.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html)

Comment: thanks! i just tried that and i still go the same original output :(

Comment: follow-up question, is there a way to join certain words, such as "give, show, nagivate, direct, and me"? during this process?

for example, if i want to combine phrasal verbs, so i can get an output like...

phrasal_verbs (direct, give, show, nagivate) = 2065

Comment: posted here, please take a look if you can:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49496102/mapping-between-words-and-a-group-tuple-to-get-frequency-of-words

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
output = {}
for i in ['starbucks','directions','navigate']:
    output[i] = df[df['Utterance'].str.lower().str.contains(i)]['Frequency'].sum()
```

Yields:

```
{'starbucks': 3666, 'directions': 2411, 'navigate': 678}
```

Comment: thanks! that will only output:

3666
2411
678

is there a way to return like a data frame above or a dictionary where i can see {'starbucks': 3666}?

thanks!

Comment: Absolutely, edited to output a dictionary of results.